# Notepad in WPF, System.IO.File.ReadAllText

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

Have troubles with opening a textfile...
Have this code, there are empty stringFromFile after called

```
    public string OpenTextFile ()
    {
        var stringFromFile = string.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog().ToString().Equals("OK"))
            stringFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
        return stringFromFile;
    }
```

Comment: You should use DialogResult class in your if instead of comparing strings.. Are you sure the text result is not "Ok"? Try putting breakpoint inside the if clause.

Comment: right....but how can i rebuild it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `ToString()` is not needed and worse, it would throw a `NullReferenceException` if the return value of `ShowDialog()` is null because `ShowDialog()` returns `bool?` (`Nullable<bool>`) as pointed out by the other answer.

Here's a two line solution...

```
string OpenTextFile()
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    return ofd.ShowDialog() == true ?
            System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName) :
            String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: it works, thank you... and thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3):

In WPF `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()`return a `Nullable<bool>` so you should change the code as follow

```
public string OpenTextFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            Nullable<bool> res = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if(res == true)
            {
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
                {
                  return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            //Here message error
            throw new Exception("Something");
        }
```